# How to guarantee that subscription was happened in stomp client?

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I have the following class:

```
@Autowired
private WebSocketStompClient client;

private volatile StompSession stompSession;

public ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect(String token) {
        .....
        //connecting
        return client.connect(settingsBean.getMarketPlaceUrl(),
                new WebSocketHttpHeaders(headers),
                stompHeadersConnect,
                new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
                        stompSession = session;
                        ...
                        session.subscribe(stompHeadersSubscribe, myFrameHandler);
                         // As I understand I don't have guarantees that subscription was completed successfully
                    }

}

public void send(String url, Object obj) {
    stompSession.send(url, obj);
}
```

Sometimes send method invokes when connect has already been established, but subscribtion - was not yet.

How to await moment when subscription have been established?

Comment: your question is **really** hard to read, could you please rephrase it? I think asking someone who speaks english to help you might be a good idea

Comment: @specializt I tried to change a bit. Is it clear now?

Comment: ..... no, sorry - something about method invocations and subscriptions (?), thats about everything i can decipher.

Comment: @specializt not about invocation - about connection and about subscription. I need to know when subscription already established

Comment: simply create a new `boolean` instance / member variable *(something like `private volatile boolean isSubscribed = false;`, perhaps)* and set it to `true` during your very first call of `afterConnected` - and check it each time. Thats basic programming.

Comment: @specializt, afterConnect invokes after connect establishing. Connect and subscribe - 2 different operations.

Comment: not in your case - you are subscribing within `afterConnected`.

Comment: @specializt But if  **session.subscribe** is executed -we don't have guarantees that subscription was established